# $ \sup(A\cup B)=\max\{\sup(A),\sup(B)\} $ proofing by contradiction

Tags: real-analysis

I cannot comprehend the following proof of:

> Let be $ A,B\subseteq \mathbb{R} $ nonempty sets and upper bounded. Then $ \sup(A\cup B)=\max\{\sup(A),\sup(B)\} $.

For the following proof this ***statement*** is used:

> ***Let $ M\subseteq \mathbb{R} $ nonempty and upper bounded and let $ s\in \mathbb{R} $. Then are equivalent:***
>
> ***i) $ s=\sup(M) $***
>
> ***ii) $ s $ is an upper bound of $ M $ and for all $ \varepsilon>0 $ exists an element $ x\in M $ with $ s-\varepsilon<x $.***

Her is the proof by contradiction:

> **The proof:** Let $ m:=\max\{\sup(A),\sup(B)\} $ and let be $ x\in (A\cup B) $ arbitrary. Then $ x\in A $ or $ x\in B $ such that $ x\leq
> \sup(A) $ or $ x\leq \sup(B) $. So $ A\cup B $ is also upper bounded
> and $  m $ is an upper bound.
>
> W.L.O.G let $ \sup(A)\leq \sup(B) $ and thus $ m=\sup(B) $. Suppose $\tilde{m} $ is also an upper bound of $ A\cup B $ with $ \tilde{m}<m
> $. Then $ \tilde{m}<\sup(B) $ and with the upper ***statement*** and $
>  \varepsilon\in ]0,\sup(B)-\tilde{m}[ $ we can find an element $ b=\sup(B)-\varepsilon \in B $ with $ \tilde{m}<b\leq \sup(B) $. But
> then $ b $ is also in $ A\cup B $ such that $ \tilde{m} $ cannot be an
> upper bound. That is a contradiction.

I think $ b=\sup(B)-\varepsilon $ cannot be an element in $ B $ because $ 0<\varepsilon<\sup(B)-\tilde{m} $. I was thinking about a picture like this:
[image]

So if I start from $ m=\sup(B) $ and go to the left less than $ m-\tilde{m} $ I cannot reach $ B $. Or did I forget something?

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you mean is that since $\tilde{m}$ is an upper bound then there will be no $b$ superior to $\tilde{m}$, but as $m = \sup(B)$ is true, we have a contradiction. Actually, we can also find a contradiction if we start from $\tilde{m}$ is an upper bound. As it is an upper bound,$\forall b \in B, b\leq \tilde{m} \implies \forall b \in B, \exists \epsilon = m-\tilde{m}, m-(m-\tilde m) \geq b $. And we have got a negation of the upper statement, which should be true since it is a condition of the quesiton, thus we have a contradiction.

Comment: I have the following idea. Because $ m $ is an upper bound by ***statement*** for all $ \varepsilon>0 $ exists an $ x\in A\cup B $ with $ m-\varepsilon<x $. So it also follows with $ \varepsilon=m-\tilde{m}>0 $. In conclusion we get $ \tilde{m}=m-(m-\tilde{m})=m-\varepsilon<x $. So $ \tilde{m} $ is not an upper bound of $ A\cup B $ which is a contradiction to the assumption that $ \tilde{m} $ is a smaller upper bound of $ A\cup B $.